# JavaScript 'undefined' error for getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get the children of a certain div which has the class "vid_div selected". I get the right div like this:

```
var vid_div = document.getElementsByClassName('vid_div selected');
```

But when I try to get its children it is undefined:

```
var vid = vid_div.children; //this returns undefined
```

Comment: You are seeing this error because getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns NodeList (collection of nodes). You have to specify index of that collection.

```
var vid_div = document.getElementsByClassName('vid_div selected');
var vid = vid_div[0].children;
```

Comment: Also, `vid_div` isn't *actually* an `Array` of nodes, but rather a `NodeList`. It behaves mostly the same as an `Array`, but you won't be able to do things like `map` or `forEach` on a `NodeList`; you'll first need to convert it to an `Array`, usually by doing `vid_div.slice(0)`.

Comment: That's correct. I could say as well that it's Collection rather than array. I will edit that, just for you.

Comment: Thank you ! Works now (I'm new to js...)